# Navigation drawer title according to the Drawer item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have used `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("drawer_title");` and the title changes according to drawer item. But when I go back the title does not get updated. for eg: If I'm at **dashboard-fragment toolbar-title is dashboard** and after that when I go to **message-fragment toolbar-title changes to message**, but, after when **I press back button it goes back to dashboard-fragment but the title does not updated to dashboard it remains message**.
How could I update the title again??

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment use `requireActivity()` to get the activity to the activitiy's `SupportActionBar`.

So, to set the title in the fragment then use:

```
((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in onViewCreated method of your fragment:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your title here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("drawer_title");` inside `onResume()` method of your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me I just used `getActivity().setTitle("fragment_title");` inside onCreateView() method of fragment.